# Fill empty space last div

Tags: css

I have 4 divs in main div. All are floating left, the last one leaves an empty space. I want to fill that space with last div (full width).

http://jsfiddle.net/jZpWf/26/

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="col1">
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
    </div>
    <div class="col3">
    </div>    
    <div class="col4">
    </div>    
</div>

#container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    background:yellow;
}
.col1 {
    float:left;
    width:90px;
    height: 200px;
    background:red;
}
.col2 {
    float:left;
    width:130px;
    background:blue;
height: 200px;    
}
.col3 {
    float:left;
    width:130px;
    background:red;
    height: 200px;
}
.col4 {
    float:left;
    width:130px;
    background:blue;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: If your container is a fixed 600px, can't you just set the width of the last div to 250px?

Comment: Some divs will be removed/added with JS.

Comment: Just to clarify, no matter how many elements there are, the last one should fill the remaining available space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't float it left and make it 100% it will fill all the remaining space.

```
.col4 {
    background:blue;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Try [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RPUX6/74/)

Comment: Providing demos is a good way to show that your answer works:  http://tinker.io/91398 (P.S. you don't even need to set a width.  If you're overriding a width, use `auto`)

Comment: Thx forgot to paste it. Removed the width as you pointed out.

Comment: Note that technically the element will fill the WHOLE container. Only inline elements will be rendered so it appears it filled just the remaining area. Padding on the `.col4` will for example not work as expected.

Comment: It seems you can fix the issue I mentioned above with `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 1):

```
.col4 {
    float:left;
    width: 250px;
    background:blue;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Simple answer, better one soon...

better one, [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jZpWf/45/)

Answer (score 0):

the sum of the widths of the divs do not correspond to the total size available, so do not occupy the total area, this can be done using the percentage method or the CSS3 calc

Resize .col4

```
.col4 {
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    background:blue;
    height: 200px;
}
```

or

Calc Col4 with CSS3

```
.col4 {
    float:left;
    width: calc(100% - 350px);
    background:blue;
    height: 200px;
}
```